# Solving $(x+4)^2+ (y-11)^2 = 0.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help with this question that appeared in my maths exam. It was for two marks so I know that it requires very little working out. The question stated to solve for x and y.

I thought that you move the $(y-11)^2$ to the other side so:
$$(x+4)^2 = - (y-11)^2$$
And then square root both sides and therefore the answer would be no solution as you cannot square root a negative (in real analysis).

Most people solved it as $x=-4$ and $y=11,$ but surely this isn't the answer as if you solve that way, those are only 2 of many solutions to the problem.

Comment: An equation of two variables need not has many solutions. Surely $x = -4$ and $y = 11$ is the only solution to the equation,  when we talk about real numbers ofcourse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $x\neq-4$, then $(x+4)^2>0$. And if $y\neq11$, then $(y-11)^2>0$. So, yes, can have $(x+4)^2+(y-11)^2=0$ when and only when $x=-4$ and $y=11$.

Comment: Thanks so much, I was thinking that you could make the two bracket terms equal to 5 and -5 to get zero, but obviously its squared so they would both be positive.

Answer (score 1):

We have that in general for $A,B\in\mathbb R$

$$A^2+B^2=0 \iff A=B=0$$

therefore $x+4=0$ and $y-11=0$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes indeed I noticed the algebra-precalculus context. Anyway I'll add that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The formula 
$$(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=r^2$$
describes a circle.
Thus your formula is a circle around $(-4,11)$ with radius $0$. Thus, there is only one solution, that is $(-4,11)$.

Answer (score 0):

A square is either positive or zero. If you have two squares summing to nothing, then necessarily they both must be $0.$

It follows that $x=-4$ *and* $y=11.$